# Unable to remove programs

Tags: linux, apt-get

I need to remove some programs in my Deepin distro but I get this error:

```
amr@amr-PC:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove Virtual Network Editor
[sudo] Mot de passe de amr : 
E: Impossible d'obtenir le verrou /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Ressource temporairement non disponible)
E: Impossible de verrouiller le répertoire d'administration (/var/lib/dpkg/). Il est possible qu'un autre processus l'utilise.
amr@amr-PC:~$
```

Google Translate:

```
amr@amr-PC:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove Virtual Network Editor
[sudo] Password of amr :
 E: Can not get lock / var / lib / dpkg / lock - open (11: Resource 
temporarily unavailable)
E: Can not lock the administration directory (/ var / lib / dpkg /). It is 
possible that another process uses it.
amr@amr-PC:~$
```

Comment: It means that you are using `apt` somewhere else. It is currently not available.

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo apt --fix-broken autoremove`.  If that doesnt work, use `sudo reboot`, then use `apt-get --fix-broken autoremove`